# SVG and D3.js Issue with correct rotation after translate

Tags: d3.js, svg

I been struggling for hours trying figure how to get the correct rotation center point after I do the following:

1) drag the box to somewhere near the center of the screen

2) hit the test button to rotate box 90 degrees

3) drag the box to another location

4) hit the test button again to rotate another 90 degress(180)

5) The resulting rotation and translation is off. It works fine if I rotate it to 0 degrees and drag the box then hit the test button and it rotates correctly.
Please see my code:

`enter code here`https://jsfiddle.net/1ctqckhL/3/

Comment: I updated your fiddle with a working d3 include [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1ctqckhL/3/). The version JSFiddle offeres is outdated and not loaded via https. Use the one that [d3js.org/](http://d3js.org/) displays and add it under "external resources" the next time ;)

Comment: thanks for fixing my jsfiddle :)

Answer (score 0):

Its easier if you pick the right group element to put the rotate on.  Assuming you want it to rotate around the center of the svg element (i.e. around the cross hairs), you can do it like this...

---

### Key points

- transform `container2` so (0,0) is on the rotation origin
  this means translation and rotation are decoupled
- only change rotation in `move_path`
- only change translate in `zoomed`
- use `d3.transform` to manage transform elements
- simplify rotation counter using modulo operator (`%`)
- added offset to initial position of rect to generalise

---

### Working code

```js
var container2;
  var last_scale = 1;
  var last_rotation = [0, 0, 0];
  var last_translate = [0, 0];
  var zoom;
  w = window.innerWidth;
  h = window.innerHeight;
  var offsetx = w / 4;
  var offsety = h / 4;

  d3.select("#container3").attr("transform", function() {
    var tr = d3.transform(d3.select(this).attr("transform"));
    return (tr.translate = [offsetx, offsety], tr.toString())
  });

  //  document.getElementById("mid_x").style.top = h / 2 + 'px';
  //  document.getElementById("mid_y").style.left = w / 2 + 'px';
  d3.select("#test_btn").style({
    top: h - 50 + "px",
    left: "10%"
  });
  zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .center([w / 2, h / 2])
    .scaleExtent([1, 10])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

  var svg = d3.select("#svg_main")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);
  svg.append("path").attr("d", "M" + [w / 2, 0] + "L" + [w / 2, h]).style({
    stroke: "red"
  })
  svg.append("path").attr("d", "M" + [0, h / 2] + "L" + [w, h / 2]).style({
    stroke: "red"
  });

  var container2 = d3.select("#container2")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + zoom.center() + ")")
  .call(zoom),

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //include scaling and fix text just for demo...
    container3 = container2.select("#container3").attr("transform", function() {
      var tr = d3.transform(d3.select(this).attr("transform"));
      return (tr.scale = [h / 955, h / 955], tr.toString())
    });
  container3.selectAll("text").style("font-size", (12 * 955 / h) + "px").attr("dy", "0.35em");
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  var trans2 = d3.transform(container2.attr("transform"));
  container2.select("#container3").attr("transform", function() {
    var tr = d3.transform(d3.select(this).attr("transform"));
    return (tr.translate = [offsetx - trans2.translate[0], offsety - trans2.translate[1]], tr.toString())
  })
  d3.selectAll("#test_btn").on("click", move_path);

  function move_path() {

    last_rotation[0] = (last_rotation[0] += 90) % 360;

    container2.attr("transform", function() {
      var tr = d3.transform(d3.select(this).attr("transform"));
      return (tr.rotate = last_rotation, tr.toString())
    });

  }

  function zoomed() {

    d3.select(this).selectAll("g").attr("transform", function() {
      var trf = d3.transform(d3.select(this).attr("transform")),
        trn = d3.event.translate;
      return (trf.translate = [offsetx - trans2.translate[0] + trn[0], offsety - trans2.translate[1] + trn[1]], trf.toString())
    })
  }
```

```css
svg {
  display: block;
  overflow: visible;
  background: #9F0;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:100%;height:100%;border:1px solid blue;position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;overflow:hidden;">
  <div id="map_div" style="position:relative;left:0px;top:0px;border:0px solid red;width:100%;height:100%;overflow:hidden;">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="svg_main" style="border:1px solid red;">
      <g id="container1">
        <g id="container2">zoom and rotate
          <g id="container3"> offset, drag and global scale
            <rect y="0" x="0" fill="#00AEEF" stroke="#000000" width="300" height="300" />
            <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 90 8.167)" font-family="'MyriadPro-Regular'" font-size="12">top</text>
          </g>
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>
    <!--<div id="mid_x" style="height:1px;background:red;width:100%;position:absolute;top:500px;left:0px;"></div>-->
    <!--<div id="mid_y" style="height:100%;background:red;width:1px;position:absolute;top:0px;"></div>-->
  </div>
</div>
<div id="map_holder" style="display:none;"></div>
<input id="test_btn" type="button" style="position:absolute;top:500px;left:100px;" value="rotate">
```

Comment: Thanks for replying and the rotations seem to be correct but if I add another group of shapes inside the container3, the new group of shapes does not drag in sync. How do I include the zoom/scale functionality back in? Thank You :)

Comment: Well, it's impossible to answer that question unless you specify what the zoom scaling is supposed to do.  So what are you trying to achieve?  Do you want the whole green area to scale keeping the same center? Do you want the square to scale keeping the red cross-hairs as the center? Do you want the square to scale relative to the current mouse position? You need to specify...

Comment: Hi, I want the zoom to keep scaling on the red cross hairs. I am trying to make a map plan that will allow the user to drag, zoom, and rotate the custom made map. Same zooming functionality as this example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6123708

Comment: The zooming functionality is not the same as what you specified.  In the link, the constant point for scaling is the current mouse position.  You are specifying that the cross-hairs is the constant point.  They are not the same: which one are you trying for?

Comment: Sorry, I think it should be relative to the current mouse position. Most of the time the map object will take up the entire screen space. Basically the same way I had it in my jsfiddle when u use the mouse scroll. Thanks :)

Comment: The fiddle doesn't do that, otherwise the square would not move away from the mouse would it?

Comment: The constant point for scaling on the current mouse position would be good enough. Thanks :)

Comment: I fixed the group dragging issue by changing function zoomed to select container3 instead of all groups.

Comment: It doesn't select all groups, the zoom function is already selecting container3, because the zoom is called on container2, `d3.select(this).selectAll("g") === container3`. So it makes no difference to do what you said...

Comment: It will select all groups within container2.

Comment: And which groups are in container2?  ...only one ...container3.  See what I mean?

Comment: Yes, this change would not be needed but I have added more groups within container 3.